# Link errors with nupengl GLFW in VS 2015 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015, glfw, glew

I had a working project on Windows 7 using GLEW and GLFW with VS 2015. I hadn't touched it in a few months, and in the meantime got a new computer with Windows 10.I could no longer build my project, so I created a new, extremely simple project with the following source:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    return 0;
}
```

Which results in the following build error:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function _main
```

On my old machine, I had downloaded and configured the dependencies manually. This time, with the new, simple test project, I used NuGet to install nupengl.core. I was under the impression that NuGet takes care of all the project include directories, linker inputs, etc., so I didn't change any project settings. Notably, changing the includes to use FreeGLUT works:

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
```

Has anyone else gotten GLFW working with NuGet on Windows 10 with VS 2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GL and GLUT mostly go hand-in-hand: at some point you'll want to bring GLUT in. This is a assumption that I made when I created the package; a rather silly assumption considering that it has caused all this confusion.

For now use the `#include <GL/freeglut.h>` you mentioned - that will bring in GL. A package-wide refactor is coming, at which point this workaround won't be needed if you aren't using GLUT.